# Dice throwing simulation and probability c++

Tags: c++

I want to write a program to simulate a dice roll by rolling the dice 3,000 times (3,000 random numbers in the 1 to 6 coding range), then calculating the probability of 6 coming and printing it in two decimal places. I wrote the first part like this, but I have a problem with the second part.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL)); 
    std::cout << "Enter number of dice to roll: ";
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        int r = rand() % 6 + 1; // Get a number 1 to 6
        std::cout << r << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: What sort of problem do you have with the second part?

Comment: Count the number of 6s and divide by the number of triee.

Comment: How do I calculate the probability of a certain number, for example, 6, between a certain number of throws?

Comment: That's the easy part. The probability, assuming a fair die, is 1/6. You likely don't want that, you want to know what percentage of actual rolls was a 6.

Comment: Each throw is independent. Remember that. This hint should be enough.

Comment: Take a real physical die and throw it ten times. Then tell me the "probability" of 6 coming up. If you can do that physically and can describe it in English you did the first step to do it in a program. (Irrelevant whether you mean mathmatical probability which you can calculate while ignoring the results or whether you want more of a statistics value, for which you have to know the results and calculate with them).

Comment: @sweenish: `rand() % 6 + 1` is unfair though (but probably fair enough for OP).

Comment: @Jarod42 Agreed, my answer (still working) uses `<random>` and the trusty `std::mt19937`.

Comment: To put it differently, if you throw ten times and the result is "1 4 6 2 4 1 2 6 3 4" what would the correct answer be which your program should provide? Why?

Answer (score 2):

You need to count how many times dice face 6 then divide it by all times you roll the dice
So the final code is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int n , r , count6 = 0;
    cout << "Enter number of dice to roll : ";
    cin >> n;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        r = rand() % 6 + 1; // Get a number 1 to 6
        if (r == 6) count6++;
        cout << r << " ";
    }

    cout<<endl;
    float probability = (float)count6 / (float)n;
    cout<<setprecision(2)<<"Probability = "<<probability<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As was told in a comment, you have to count the number of times a 6 is rolled as opposed to just printing every roll. We store data in variables. So it follows that we need a variable to count the number of sixes.

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main() {
  constexpr int totalRolls = 3000;

  std::mt19937 prng(std::random_device{}());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> d6(1, 6);

  int numSixes = 0;  // Need a variable to count the number of 6s
  for (int i = 0; i < totalRolls; ++i) {
    if (d6(prng) == 6) {
      ++numSixes;  // Where the counting occurs
    }
  }

  // Printing is the easy part, after you figure out which stream manipulators
  // to call
  std::cout << "Out of " << totalRolls << " rolls, " << numSixes << " ("
            << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2)
            << (static_cast<double>(numSixes) / totalRolls * 100)
            << "%) were 6s.\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Out of 3000 rolls, 498 (16.60%) were 6s.
```

Your actual numbers will vary, but that's because rolls are random. I also forgo `rand()` in favor of more modern C++ implementations. In this case I use [`std::mt19937`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine). While it's likely that `rand()` is 'good enough' for this program, I would encourage you to avoid it. It's not all that random, and using modulo on top of that to get a range actually hurts it again.

In the code, I declare `int numSixes` and initialize it to 0. I roll the die by generating a random number. I then check if the number is 6. If it is, I increment (add one to) `numSixes`. After I've finished rolling the die, I know how many times I've rolled a 6, and I know how many total rolls there were (`totalRolls`). Then I print the results. You need both `std::fixed` and `std::setprecision(2)` to get 2 decimal places. Leaving out `std::fixed` will only print 2 significant digits including what comes before the `.`. Leaving out `std::precision(2)` uses the default precision, which is about 6 or so. I don't know the actual number and don't want to look it up.

An important distinction here: I am **not** calculating the probability. You could say that I'm proving it, or calculating a percentage, but the result is **not** the probability. It's very important to use terms correctly. A probability is a mathematical idea that we can calculate without tests, and tests can verify that calculation.

Comment: Instead of `(static_cast<double>(numSixes) / static_cast<double>(totalRolls) * 100)` you could use the implicit conversion to `double` in `numSixes * 100. / totalRolls` to simplify it.

Comment: I get that explicitly casting both sides is not necessary, but I prefer it over 'sneaking' my intent just to shorten the expression. I suppose if I were actually pushing this in production, I'd only cast one operand. I'll make that change. Also, thanks for catching that extra brace.